# How to define own types in Relax NG?

Tags: xml, regex, types, xsd, relaxng

Consider the following regular expression

```
pattern = "(0[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(19|20)\d\d"
```

This pattertn represents date strings in MM/DD/YYYY format. Now, if I want to create several attribues of this type, I can apparently write them like:

```
element holiday 
{
 attribute beginDate
 {
  xs:string { pattern = "(0[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(19|20)\d\d" }
 }
 attribute endDate
 {
  xs:string { pattern = "(0[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(19|20)\d\d" }
 }
}
```

But this is very inconvenient to write the pattern line every time when I want to define a date in such format. I would like to define my own type, e.g. `MyDateFormat`, and use it where necessary as `attribute someDate { MyDateFormat }` instead of rewriting the same code multiple times, but I couldn't find a way to define own types using [Relax NG compact syntax](http://relaxng.org/compact-tutorial-20030326.html). My question is how is it possible to implement such behaviour and avoid code twice rewriting.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out one solution: new type can be defined as

```
MMDDYYYY = xs:string { pattern = "(0[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(19|20)\d\d" }
```

and then use it where necessary:

```
element holiday 
{
 attribute beginDate { MMDDYYYY }
 attribute endDate   { MMDDYYYY }
}
```